# Why windows update tool is showing non-security updates for sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, administration, windows-server, patching

We have windows server 2008 R2 and sharepoint enterprise farm 2013. now as i know that around 3-4 years ago Microsoft decided not to distribute SharePoint updates (except for security fixes) via Windows Update anymore. but when i checked our windows update tool i found the following updates for sharepoint, where there is a single non-security update (marked in red), named **update for SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2920730)**, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this ? why our windows update tool is showing non security update for sharepoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only cumulative updates are not provided by Windows Update.
Others SharePoint updates are provided.

**KB2920730**

[image]

**KB4462219(March 2019 CU)**

[image]

Comment: @Ref i did not get your point.. can you please explain it in more details?

Comment: @Ref also the 2 KBs mentioned on the link `KB 4457916/4457035` are not listed inside my security updates list shown inside windows update tool..so i should be on the safe side

Comment: I've illustrated that simple updates like KB2920730 may come from Windows Update. Cumulative updates will not come from WU.

Comment: yes i know that commulative updates no longer show inside WU... but i thought that only security update will be mentioned inside WU..